# How to do a Findby In Springboot Mongo repository for Nested Objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-repositories

Need your help here in a Spring Data `CrudRepository` on how to do a `findby` of nested fields.
My class is of following structure and I need to query using `truckId` which is of the nested objects

```java
@Document(collection = "unt-truck")
public class TruckModelDTO {
    private String type;
    private TestDTO testDTO;

}
```

Class `TestDTO.java`

```java
public class TestDTO{

    private TruckDTO truckDTO;
    Private String version;

}
```

Class `TruckDTO.java`

```java
public class TruckDTO {

    private String truckId;
    private String legacySystem;

}
```

Class `TruckRepository.java`

```java
@Repository
public interface TruckRepository extends MongoRepository<TruckModelDTO, String> {


    // TruckModelDTO findByTruckId(String truckid);

}
```

So how should I use `findby` for `truckId` which is inside a nested class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use with either Entity or DTO as response. but you have to mention the relation between two or three Entity based on you requirement.

I have created Entity. you have to create DTO with same based on entity then apply main DTO as return type in JPA Repository query.

1.Entity

```
@Entity
public class TruckModel {
    private String type;

    // mention the relation based on your requirement
    private Test test;

}
```

2. Entity

```
@Entity
public class Test {
    // here mention the relation based on you requirement
    private Truck truck;
    Private String version;

}
```

3.Entity

```
@Entity
public class Truck {

    private String truckId;
    private String legacySystem;

}
```

4. Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TruckModelRepository extends 
    MongoRepository<TruckModel, String> {
        TruckModelDTO findByTestTruckTruckId(String truckid);

}
```